# BufferedImage is not changing the colour of all white parts of the image

Tags: java, colors, bufferedimage

I have a set of black and white Kanji characters images that I am trying to change the colour of. I want all white parts of the white image (i.e., all parts of the image that is not the character) to turn a particular colour. I am doing this with BufferedImages, by using a for loop to loop through every pixel in the image, check if it is white, and then change the white colour to a colour passed to the method. Here is the code for the method in question:

```
public static void illuminateImage(BufferedImage elementImage, Color elementColor){
    for (int j = 0; j < elementImage.getWidth(); j++){
        for (int k = 0; k < elementImage.getHeight(); k++){
            if(elementImage.getRGB(j, k) == Color.WHITE.getRGB()){//images1.get(0).getRGB(0, 0)){
                elementImage.setRGB(j,k, elementColor.getRGB());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is is that not every white pixel is changing color. When I call the method, all parts of the image that are not the Kanji character do not change colour. While most of it changes color, there are some white patches in part. Why is this occurring?

I thought a way around this would be to instead write code that checks if the pixels are not black, and then change them to the given colour if so. However, that doesn't work, and just turns the entire image the given colour, I think because the characters are not strictly in black, even though they look like it. I don't know how to get the colour of the characters. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There's obviously a really good chance that not all pixels colors within your images are as simple as black (0,0,0) and white (255,255,255). You will need to think in ranges of black and white or modify the pixels in each image to be true black and white.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that all of your "white" isn;t exactly white, and that all of your black isn't black (from what you said).

What you should be doing is printing out every color in the kanji, to see what's going on.

Something such as.

```
    public static void illuminateImage(BufferedImage elementImage, Color elementColor)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < elementImage.getWidth(); j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < elementImage.getHeight(); k++)
           {
              System.out.println(elementImage.getRGB(j, k));
           }
        }
    }
```

From there your choices are.

1. Change everything to white and black (not sure where these images are coming from, but you should have them be the correct colors of white and black, so you will have to edit them with a program like Photoshop, or personally manipulate them using code.
2. Instead of looking for a color, look for a range of colors, or look into finding HUES, granted this might be more difficult for shades of white/black.

IMO I would look into what the range of WHITE is, and then searching that entire range to see if the color is in there i.e., 200,200,200-255,255,255 to cover all possibilties of "white" but would probably be way more than needed, so check some color charts.

Since your Kanji should be black/white, you shouldn't have an issue finding a range and it affecting the rest of your application.

This site should provide some interesting info on Chroma-Keying.

http://www.lac.inpe.br/JIPCookbook/6520-howto-chromakey.jsp

Overall, you will need to figure out what color the other pixels are, then figure out if you will edit them manually, with a program like photoshop, or just test ranges.

Good luck.

---

Code to find RGB values.

```
Color c = new Color(elementImage.getRGB(j, k));

  System.out.println(c.getRed() +  " | " + c.getGreen() + " | " + c.getBlue() );
```

to convert back into integer you look at your values.

B encompasses 0-7 bits, G is 8-15, and R is 16-24.

You will do 
(2^16*Red) + (2^8 *Green) + (Blue) to get your integer value again.

---

Just to add to this, we discovered  that the OP is using the Alpha channel so his white value is -1, which is correct.

So OP just needs to make sure that he is within a certain threshold using the RGB values in order to select or not, instead of the integer value, which would be harder to figure out.

Comment: I'm a bit confused because the values that you gave are not RGB values, right? I'm confused as to how to find the RGB range of white.

Comment: I did give you RGB values 255 Red, 255 Green, and 255 Blue is white. 0,0,0 is black.  Now, in this case we could really just get each value of red green and blue, and check to see if they are all above 200.  so I will edit this above.

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is that when you print out the RGB values, they come up as one integer, not three. How do I convert that RGB code to the one in which only one value is presented?

Comment: For instance, when I get the RGB of black, it comes out as 1. It doesn't print out three integers.

Comment: Do you mean on the link to that site you sent me? I can't find on there where it converts from three integers to one.

Comment: sorry, I got confused as I was looking at my example, and not the link.  What you can do is create a new color, and then do color.getRed() blue, green, and then figure it out that way.  You can then convert it back to an integer later.

Comment: OK, now I'm really confused, because I found a converter online. White (255, 255, 255) converts to 1672215, and yet if I print out every pixel of an image before I change its color, non of the numbers come out as that value, which is impossible, because some of the images DO change colour when I say change colour if white.

Comment: yup, that is white I believe.

Comment: I don't understand how that's possible. Shouldn't the majority of pixels be coming out as that value when I run print statements (because the majority of pixels are changing color when I say change color if white)? This doesn't make sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110331/discussion-between-lasagna-and-lb91).

Answer (score 0):

```
   public static void illuminateImage(BufferedImage elementImage, Color elementColor)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < elementImage.getWidth(); j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < elementImage.getHeight(); k++)
           {
              Color c = new Color(elementImage.getRGB(j, k));
              c.getBlue();
              c.getGreen();
              c.getRed();
           }
        }
    }

public static void illuminateImage(BufferedImage elementImage, Color elementColor){
    int threshold = 300;//You can try other threshold
    for (int j = 0; j < elementImage.getWidth(); j++){
        for (int k = 0; k < elementImage.getHeight(); k++){
            if(elementImage.getRGB(j, k) >= (Color.WHITE.getRGB() + threshold)){//images1.get(0).getRGB(0, 0)){
                elementImage.setRGB(j,k, elementColor.getRGB());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This way can get red green blue value

Comment: A threshold is useful, but you need to apply it to the color components (R, G, B) individually. Just adding an arbitrary number to the packed ARGB value, will likely cause overflow of one or more components and not match the intended color (but some other non-intended color instead).

Comment: Yes, the issue was solved by checking if each value was above 200, but that value might change as well.  For now the OP said it works.  I personally might just change everything to exactly white and black, but if this works out for the OP, then that's all that matters.